# Rails how to copy all active storage attachments to new object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

I have a function to clone records in a rails application. In addition to the form data I would like to copy/attach any active storage file uploads that are attached to the source object to the new object. Any ideas on how to do this? Here is my action:

```
def copy
  @source = Compitem.find(params[:id])
  @compitem = @source.dup
  render 'new'
end

class Compitem < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 has_many_attached :uploads, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: ActiveStorage attachments are stored on the blobs table. So "cloning" a record would at least mean that you have to duplicate those rows. But you also have to consider if the blobs on the duplicated object should point to the same stored file (on for example s3) or if it should duplicate the file. What have you actually researched? I can only see the vaguest of attempts here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The files are stored in local storage. I would like to create new attachments and duplicate the objects rather than keep the same attachments and just link them both to the same. Does that make sense? I looked around and see some options for copying over one file in the case of has_one but haven't been able to get it to work with a has_many copy all attachments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting this working by using the https://github.com/moiristo/deep_cloneable gem. Final action:

```
  def copy
   @source = Compitem.find(params[:id])
   @compitem = @source.deep_clone(include: :uploads_blobs)
   @compitem.save
   render 'new'
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Just did this in one of my applications - it was a has_one rather than has_many but I think something like this should work for you, without adding any additional dependencies, in Rails 6+:

```
@compitem  = @source.dup
@source.uploads.each do |original_file|
  @compitem.uploads.attach(io: StringIO.new(original_file.download),
                           filename: original_file.filename,
                           content_type: original_file.content_type)
end

@compitem.save
```